# Img srcset auto resizing

Tags: css, html, image, srcset

While using img srcset with no css applied to the document, I can resize the browser width and the image width changes responsively so that the full image is always displayed (but smaller).

How can I make it so that it works like a standard image tag?

e.g. Resize browser window doesn't change image size...

```html
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      srcset="http://lorempixel.com/160/200/ 160w, 
               http://lorempixel.com/320/200/ 320w, 
               http://lorempixel.com/640/200/ 640w, 
               http://lorempixel.com/1280/200/ 1280w">
```

Comment: ummm... `<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />` What are you asking?

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean what I think you mean then this should help, put this with the CSS file and the images will resize with the page resize.

```
img { height:100%; width:auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

same issue here srcset doesn't work when resizing screen, but picture + source are working

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}


<img src="images/1000/1.jpg" srcset="images/200/1.jpg 320w, images/1000/1.jpg 800w, images/1500/1.jpg 1200w, images/2500/1.jpg 1600w">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need sizes to make it responsive:

```
<img srcset="large.jpg  1024w,
      medium.jpg 640w,
      small.jpg  320w"
   sizes="(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw,
      100vw"
   src="small.jpg"/>
```

If you're going to make the img load the new source you need to refresh the page. As the browser pics the image on load.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x` descriptor instead of `w` descriptor, or specify the size you want in the `sizes` attribute (which is required when using `w`).

Comment: The w descriptor cover cover the case of x. The way it works is that 'w' descriptors are calculated into 'x' descriptors by dividing the given value with the effective size from the sizes attribute.